# How to inverse transform both ordinal and label encoding?

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding

So, currently I am trying to inverse transform after making predictions with my model. I had encoded all features using label encoding, but realized that some were ordinal, so I changed those to be ordinal encoded and all seems good there. But, I ran into an issue and was getting the error: "ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: [2]"

After examining it, I realized the issue must lie in the fact that some of the features in possible_combinations aren't label encoded, they're ordinal encoded. But, I am not sure how I would go about inverse_transform when attempting to do it for some label encoded features and some ordinal encoded
Here are some examples of where I encode features

```
combined_data['main_flavor_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(combined_data['main_flavor'])
combined_data['secondary_flavor_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(combined_data['secondary_flavor'])
combined_data['ranking_encoded'] = ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(combined_data[['ranking']])
combined_data['age_category_encoded'] = ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(combined_data[['age_category']])
```

and here is my model predict and then the inverse transform

```
predictions = model.predict(possible_combinations[features])
    
    # Get the index of the combination with the lowest predicted factor
    best_idx = np.argmin(predictions)
    
    # Get the location and flavor_type corresponding to the best index
    best_location = possible_combinations.loc[best_idx, 'location_encoded']
    best_flavor_type_encoded = possible_combinations.loc[best_idx, 'flavor_type_encoded']
    best_flavor_type = label_encoder.inverse_transform([best_flavor_type_encoded])[0]
```

Comment: Can you add some code of how you label and/or ordinal encoded the data?

Comment: yep! just edited to add that

Answer (score 1):

By using the `inverse_transform` method of the appropriate encoder for each type of encoding, you can correctly convert the encoded values back to their original form.

It looks like the error you're encountering,

> "ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels,"

is occurring because you're using `label_encoder.fit_transform()` on different parts of your dataset independently.

To fix this issue and ensure consistency in encoding, follow these steps:

1. For each categorical variable, use a single encoder for the entire dataset to ensure consistent encoding. Don't fit separate encoders for different portions of your data.

From your example code:

```py
# Initialize encoders
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder()

# Fit encoders on the entire dataset
combined_data['main_flavor_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(combined_data['main_flavor'])
combined_data['secondary_flavor_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(combined_data['secondary_flavor'])
combined_data['ranking_encoded'] = ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(combined_data[['ranking']])
combined_data['age_category_encoded'] = ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(combined_data[['age_category']])
```

2. If you have new data (like possible_combinations in your case), you should transform it using the already-fit encoders to ensure consistent encoding.

```py
# Assuming 'flavor_type_encoded' is label encoded and 'location_encoded' is ordinal encoded
predictions = model.predict(possible_combinations[features])

best_idx = np.argmin(predictions)
best_location = possible_combinations.loc[best_idx, 'location_encoded']
best_flavor_type_encoded = possible_combinations.loc[best_idx, 'flavor_type_encoded']

# Inverse transform using the appropriate encoders
best_flavor_type = label_encoder.inverse_transform([best_flavor_type_encoded])[0]
best_location_original = ordinal_encoder.inverse_transform([[best_location]])[0][0]
```

- LabelEncoder

  - [inverse_transform(y)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.inverse_transform) - Transform labels back to original encoding.
- OrdinalEncoder

  - [inverse_transform(X)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.inverse_transform) - Convert the data back to the original representation.